# Error running heroku python local using windows during the tutorial

Tags: python, heroku

I 'm following the [Heroku tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#declare-app-dependencies) and at the step where I am runnig it locally. I am now having an issue doing this. It gives me the following error when I run the command

```
heroku local web -f Procfile.windows

forego | starting web.1 on port 5000
web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web.1  | ango\contrib\auth\models.py", line 41, in <module>
web.1  | roperlyConfigured(error_msg)
PS D:\heroku\python-getting-started>
```

Any Idea what this could be?